# Jquery toggle back other elements when new toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a table with months as header. When clicked on month i want to display weeks in all tds of corresponding header. I am using toggle for this. How can I toggle back other elements when I click on a new header.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/57BmW/16/). Here after first click it is taking two clicks to do the job. What is going wrong? Is there any other concise ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('th').click(

    function() {
        // hide all expanded
        $('#ex td #td_data').show();
        $('#ex td #o_data').hide();

        // show only corresponding weeks
        $('#ex td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').each(function(index) {
            $(this).find('#td_data').hide();
            $(this).find('#o_data').show();
        });

    });

});​
```

---

> EDIT:

@Sami - I think I get your requirement now...

Check the modifie fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/JYkS6/

-> I removed the css for #o_data

-> id for each element should be unique - changed this to class instead

-> Modified the above code like below

```
$('.o_data').hide();
$('.td_data').show();
$('th').click(

function() {
    var id = $(this).index() + 1;

     //loop through corresponding tds and display data
    $('#ex td:nth-child(' + id + ')').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('.td_data').toggle();
        $(this).find('.o_data').toggle();
    });   

     //reset everything else
    $('#ex td').not(':nth-child(' + id + ')').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('.td_data').show();
        $(this).find('.o_data').hide();
    });   

});​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for right answer and good logic. I will be using click function instead of toggle as it solves my problem in concise way.

Comment: On a second thought :- I would have been using click. But again i can't toggle back the header which is expanded by clicking on it again. The problem is solved with this example so I'm accepting it. I used .show() and .hide() in toggled function and wallah problem solved. Thanks again...

Comment: HI @johnbk sorry for toggling acceptance on and off. The fiddle is edited. I still need two clicks to get the job done.

Comment: @Sami - Not sure if I understood you right...I see the same fiddle, can you explain the problem a bit more?

Comment: Its updated now. What i want to do is toggle back other elements when a th is clicked. i used .show() and .hide() rather than setting variables true and false. But now its taking two clicks to do the job.

Comment: @Sami - I don't see the updated file yet, but I can see why you need two clicks - toggle just cycles through each of the functions you supplied - that is the first function is executed on 1st, 3rd, 5th clicks, 2nd function is executed on 2nd, 4th and 6th....clicks for each header - you got to change your logic to make it work with 'toggle' as expected - I think 'toggle' is not the correct approach for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/aKPDT/2/

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("th").click(function(){
        var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
          $(".col"+myClass).toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table id='ex' border='1'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th  class="1">Jan</th>
                    <th  class="2">Feb</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="td_data">#11</div>
                        <div id="o_data" class="col1">
                            <span>Week1</span><span>Week2</span><span>Week3</span><span>week4</span>
                        </div>                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="td_data">#12</div>
                        <div id="o_data" class="col2"><span>Week1</span><span>Week2</span><span>Week3</span><span>week4</span></div>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="td_data">#21</div>
                        <div id="o_data" class="col1"><span>Week1</span><span>Week2</span><span>Week3</span><span>week4</span>
                        </div>                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="td_data">#22</div>
                        <div id="o_data" class="col2">
                            <span>Week1</span><span>Week2</span><span>Week3</span><span>week4</span></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Comment: this doesnt solve OP's issue, first div is not hidden when second one is displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
$('th').click(function(){
    var i = $('th').index(this);
    $('tr').each(function(index){
        var x = $(this).children('td').eq(i).find('div').eq(0);
        var y = $(this).children('td').eq(i).find('div').eq(1);
        $(x).toggle();
        $(y).toggle();
    });
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57BmW/7/